# How to programmatically change the index.html and index.css in a electron app build by electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder, asar

I have build an application in electron that has an open port that waits for configuration to be send. On my development environment once I send a configuration the index.html and index.css change the then the main window is reloaded.

However, when the application is packaged with electron-builder the index.html and index.css do not change.

The application still listens and replies back correctly.

I know that the whole of the application gets packaged into the app.asar and that it basically is an archive.

Is there a way that the two files I want to be changing programmatically to either not be included in the app.asar or any other solution.

Comment: So, you're saying that your application *permanently* alters its source whenever a specific event is received? What's your use-case for this? Surely there's a more elegant solution to that... In the meantime, you could try not to package your app's source into an ASAR file, by specifying `"asar": false` in the appropriate place in your configuration (cf. [EB's docs](https://electron.build)) but mind you that this will simply create a directory containing your app's full source.